# SQL ,Count Data in column ,Undesired results?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am counting a specific columns data occurance in SQL Server.

The criteria is to get a Staff members data via a unique Number assigned to that staff member. The count needs to be between two dates.

This is what I have thus far,
I am counting the value `Data_1` and how many times it occurs in the column name `Info_Data`, `BETWEEN '2016/6/15' AND '2016/7/16'` from the Column `Staff_No` who's number is `3201`

```
SELECT S.Staff_No, S.Info_Data, C.cCount
  FROM Staff_Manager.dbo.Staff_Time_TBL  S 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Info_Data, count('Data_1') as cCount
                     FROM Staff_Manager.dbo.Staff_Time_TBL  
                    GROUP BY Info_Data) C ON S.Info_Data = C.Info_Data 
                    WHERE Staff_No = 3201 AND Date_Data BETWEEN '2016/6/15' AND '2016/7/16'
```

The results are not what I was expecting and are as below. `Data_1` occurs 9 times between those two dates.

```
No  |  Staff_No  |  Info_Data  |  cCount   
1   |  3201      |  Data_1     |  3456  
2   |  3201      |  Data_1     |  3456  
3   |  3201      |  Data_1     |  3456  
4   |  3201      |  Data_1     |  3456  
5   |  3201      |  Data_1     |  3456  
6   |  3201      |  Data_1     |  3456  
7   |  3201      |  Data_1     |  3456  
8   |  3201      |  Data_1     |  3456  
9   |  3201      |  Data_1     |  3456
```

So it seems to be counting all the occurrences of `Data_1` in column `cCount` and repeating the rows `9` times. When it should look like this below.

```
No  |  Staff_No  |  Info_Data  |  cCount  
1   |  3201      |  Data_1     |  9
```

How to amend the SQL to get the desired results? I am guessing I have the `WHERE` in the wrong place, but I can't get anything else to work?

Comment: well, you're joining to the Staff_Time_TBL in a way that it's not counting the dates, it's only getting a count of all the occurrences against each info_data. EDIT: I'm not seeing why you need the join at all. Just count the occurrences in your Staff_Time_TBL where the date is between your dates and group by staff_no, info_data

Comment: e.g. `SELECT Staff_No, Info_Data, COUNT(*) cCount FROM Staff_Time_TBL WHERE Staff_No = 3201 AND Date_Data BETWEEN '2016/6/15' AND '2016/7/16' GROUP BY Staff_No, Info_Data` or are you looking for something different here? Note: If your DateData column is DATETIME and not DATE, I would recommend against using `BETWEEN`.

Comment: @ZLK, that works perfectly.  BTW, it is a DATE not DATETIME, that has bit me on the butt before. If you want to add answer I would like to up vote and mark the answer as solved for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to get the desired results you just need to do a regular count with a group by statement.

```
SELECT Staff_No, Info_Data, COUNT(*) cCount
FROM Staff_Manager.dbo.Staff_Time_TBL
WHERE Staff_No = 3201 
AND Date_Data BETWEEN '2016/6/15' AND '2016/7/16'
GROUP BY Staff_No, Info_Data;
```

What your query was actually doing was getting each of the times it occurred as separate rows, and then showing a count of all the occurrences of Info_Data ('Data_1') in your Staff_Time_TBL (without caring about the date, because the date isn't part of the subquery in the join).

Comment: Thanks again for the help, much appreciated.